# Can't pass right number of args via NodeJS spawnSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, terminal

Running this command using `spawnSync` use to work before I added in `npx`.

```
spawnSync(`npx git add-coauthor ${commandKey} "${name}" ${email}`)
```

Now I get an error from the `git-mob` cli saying `Incorrect Number of Parameters`. It sees four instead of three after `add-coauthor` it seems like it's ignoring the double quotes around name.

Error: "Incorrect Number of Parameters [ 'zsgi', 'first', 'lastname', 'someone@email.com' ]\n"

Things I've tried but I get the same error:

```js
spawnSync(
  "npx",
  ["git", "add-coauthor", commandKey, `"${name}"`, email]
);


spawnSync(
  `npx git add-coauthor "${commandKey} \"${name}\" ${email}"`
);
```

If I run Git Mob cli command directly in the terminal this works:

```sh
npx git add-coauthor "jsj \"alsk la\" sls@al.com"
```

Grateful for any suggestions.

The code can be [found here](https://github.com/rkotze/git-mob-vs-code/blob/master/src/git/commands.js#L90).

#### Edits: More info

This could be related to Windows 10 cmd as it seems to work fine on Mac OS.

Node version: `12.11.0`

Npm version: `6.11.3`

Comment: Running the command with double backslash seems to work on windows, not sure why.

`npx git add-coauthor ${commandKey} \\"${name}\\" ${email}`